why do i have link error after including FLTK library
i am a novice at coding in C++,i have installed FLTK library using VCPKG, after creating a new project to test the library i had a link error: "cannot open file 'fltk_jepegd.lib'" .
the code for testing the library is:
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.h>
int main()
{
    Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
    Fl_Box box(0, 0, 200, 200, "Hey, I mean, Hello, World!");
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
}

i am using visual studio 2022 community,
what is the reason for this link error?
i have searched the web but could not find a solution.

The most likely reason is that you have not told the linker where to find that library.

Menu item Project/Properties then Linker/General/Additional Library Directories and enter the directory containing your library there.

a handy way to do so (MS only...) is to use pragma: #pragma comment(lib, "myxxxxLIB.lib")

Are you using a static library or  dynamic library?

@ thanks for the comments guys i appreciate it @john ,@ingconti

yes @MinxinYu-MSFT

Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue!  See can I answer my own question, Just a reminder :)

@MinxinYu-MSFT , oh yeah I see , unfortunately I can't answer because of my reputation,  this is the most stern QA website I dealt with so it's not beginner friendly at all.

There are no reputation requirement for answering. We see answers by 1-rep users all the time.
